# Not configured validation message shown in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorstrap

Have an `input type="number"` field on page, defined as `BlazorStrap` element

```
<BSInput InputType="InputType.Number" @bind-Value="data.NumField" ValidateOnInput="true" />
<BSFeedback For="@(() => data.NumField)" />
```

In model it goes like

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is required")]
[Range(1, 99999, ErrorMessage = "Use number between 1 and 99999")]
public int? NumField { get; set; }
```

- If field is empty - getting message `Field is required` (ok)
- If i enter value `-1` - getting message `Use number between 1 and 99999` (ok)
- If i enter value `9000000000` - getting two messages `Use number between 1 and 99999` and `Value cannot be greater than 2147483647` (not ok)

How can i adjust my validation to see only single validation message `Use number between 1 and 99999` in case of number not from defined range is entered, and keep `Field is required` message in case of empty field?

Comment: What is BSInput and BSFeedback? The error message comes from there. The error occurs because it overflows the int data type.

Comment: It looks like you're getting one message from the control and one from the validator. Probably write your own input control, try and customize `BSInput`, or build a custom version of InputNumber.

Comment: `BSInput`/`BSFeedback` are from `BlazorStrap` library. As i found, `BSFormFeedback` has `InvalidMessage` parameter, but with it i can only have one validation message for all cases.

Comment: Are you glued to using `BSInput`?  That's were your problem lies.  Without intimate knowledge of BlazorStrap code, you're not going to modify that behaviour.

Comment: When the value you input can't be parsed into int ,the value parameter of IsValid method would be null, you have to follow this document to custom the error message:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#server-validation-with-a-validator-component

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement your validation like below:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class RequiredRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private int _min;
    private int _max;

    public RequiredRangeAttribute (int min, int max)
    {
        _min = min;
        _max = max;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Field is required");
        }

        if (!int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int number))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid number format");
        }

        if (number < _min || number > _max)
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"Use number between {_min} and {_max}");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

and then use it like below:

```
[RequiredRange(1, 99999, ErrorMessage = "Use number between 1 and 99999")]
public int? NumField { get; set; }
```

Comment: Getting same result with given custom validation. Two messages `Use number between 1 and 99999` and `Value cannot be greater than 2147483647`

Comment: That's because `Value cannot be greater than 2147483647` is coming from type validation within the `BSInput` control.  This doesn't address that.